# Regex Assistance for a url filepath

Tags: regex

Can someone assist in creating a Regex for the following situation:

I have about 2000 records for which I need to do a search/repleace where I need to make a replacement for a known item in each record that looks like this:

```
<li><a href="http://www.website.com/FILEPATH/FILE" target="_blank">View Product Information</a></li>
```

The FILEPATH and FILE are variable, but the surrounding HTML is always the same. Can someone assist with what kind of Regex I would substitute for the "FILEPATH/FILE" part of the search?

Comment: What language are you attempting to do this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may match the constant part and use grouping to put it back

```
(<li><a href="http://www\.website\.com/)[^"]*(" target="\_blank">View Product Information</a></li>)
```

then you should replace the string with `$1your_replacement$2`, where `$1` is the first matching group and `$2` the second (if using python for instance you should call `Match.group(1)` and `Match.group(2)`)

You would have to escape `\` chars if you're using Java instead.